# Compare Decimals in Bash while Loop

Tags: bash, floating-point, shellcheck

In the below code, [ShellCheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) throws an error in the `while` clause.

```
count=10.0
while [ $count -le 20.0 ]
do
    echo "Hello"
    count=$(bc<<< "scale=4; (count+0.1)")
done
```

ShellCheck says:

> Decimals not supported, either use integers or bc

I am not quite sure how to use bc in a `while` loop.

```
while [ $(bc <<< "scale=4; (count -le 20.0)" ]
```

How do I compare decimal numbers in a while clause? Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash doesn't support floating point arithmetic.
You can either use bc:

```
count="10.0"
limit="12.0"
increment="0.1"

while [ "$(bc <<< "$count < $limit")" == "1"  ]; do
    echo "Hello"
    count=$(bc <<< "$count+$increment")
done
```

or awk:

```
while awk 'BEGIN { if ('$count'>='$limit') {exit 1}}'; do
    echo "Hello"
    count=$(bc <<< "$count+$increment")
done
```

I just wonder: why not (directly) count from 10.0 to 12.0 ?

```
for i in $(seq 10.0 0.1 12.0); do
    echo "Hello"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash doesn't support floating pointing arithmetic. You can use `bc` for that comparison too:

```
count=10.0

while : ;
do
    out=$(bc -l<<< "$count<20.0")
    [[ $out == 0 ]] && { echo "Reached limit" ; exit 0; }

    echo "Hello"
    count=$(bc<<< "scale=4; ($count+0.1)")
done
```

Note that I added the missing `$` to `count` inside the loop where you update `count`.

Answer (score 0):

While bash doesn't handle floating point numbers, the `seq` utility does. [Note 1]

The basic syntax is `seq FIRST INCREMENT LAST`, so in your case you could use

```
for count in "$(seq 10.0 0.1 20.0)"; do
  # something with $count
done
```

If you provide two arguments, they are assumed to be FIRST and LAST, with INCREMENT being 1. If you provide only one argument, it is assumed to be LAST, with both FIRST and INCREMENT being 1. As in your example, the sequence is *inclusive* so both FIRST and LAST will be produced provided that INCREMENT evenly divides FIRST−LAST.

You can also include an explicit format:

```
$ seq -f "%06.3f" 1 .5 2
01.000
01.500
02.000
```

One downside of this technique is that it precomputes the entire collection of values. If the loop will execute hundreds of thousands of times, that might use up a lot of memory, in which case you could use a pipe or process substitution instead:

```
while read count; do
  # something with count
done < <(seq 10.0 0.000001 20.0)
```

---

#### Notes

1. `seq` is not Posix but it is almost always present; it's part of GNU coreutils and a similar utility, available in Mac OS X) has been in NetBSD since 3.0 and FreeBSD since 9.0.